# What is a Spectral Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Spectral Word™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Spectral Words™ | Not Spectral Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ACTION | REACTION |
| BERRY | OLIVE |
| FIELD | YARD |
| HAMMER | GAVEL |
| HEAD | BRAIN |
| HOUSE | IGLOO |
| PRINT | VIEW |
| RAFT | WHEEL |
| SICKNESS | OVERHEATED |
| STONE | BOW |
| THROAT | NOSTRIL |
| TIN | IRON |
| TOOTH | ARM |
| WOOD | RAIN |

CSV version:

```
Spectral Words™,Not Spectral Words™
ACTION,REACTION
BERRY,OLIVE
FIELD,YARD
HAMMER,GAVEL
HEAD,BRAIN
HOUSE,IGLOO
PRINT,VIEW
RAFT,WHEEL
SICKNESS,OVERHEATED
STONE,BOW
THROAT,NOSTRIL
TIN,IRON
TOOTH,ARM
WOOD,RAIN
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Spectral Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of Spectral Words™, many more exist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I have the answer:

> A spectral word is one that can be prefixed by a colour of the rainbow to produce another word:
>  
>  action → REDaction
> berry → BLUEberry
> field → GREENfield
> hammer → YELLOWhammer
> head → REDhead
> house → GREENhouse
> print → BLUEprint
> raft → REDraft
> sickness → GREENsickness
> stone → REDstone
> throat → REDthroat
> tin → INDIGOtin
> tooth → BLUEtooth
> wood → REDwood

Comment: Looks good, but what about REDneck?

Comment: @MOehm That is a very good question.

Comment: What's greensickness?

Comment: @MOehm: Well spotted! I'll quickly edit that one out :P

Comment: @CraigMcMahon It's an alternative name for [chlorosis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chlorosis#medicalDictionary).

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: Did you notice the pattern in the Not Spectral Words? Or did you solve it without those hints?

Comment: There was a pattern in the Not Spectral Words? No, I didn't notice. The word _spectral_ was a bit of a giveaway...

Comment: It's always difficult to come up with a title that conveys some meaning and yet doesn't point to directly into the right direction. As for the pattern: look at the first letters of the Not Spectral Words ;)

Comment: @Levieux The clue which points towards the answer is a good clue. And this particular was a good one :) This one one stands by most of the [rules](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5811/what-is-an-xyz-item-puzzles-what-not-to-do) I guess.

Comment: @Levieux: looks safe now. `:)` Well done on the extra hint in the NSWs, which I failed to spot.